# Why different battery voltage does not affect LED light-up time?

Tags: breadboard

[image: ad]I have this clock circuit build along with de-bouncing circuit - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6xdOexSCE (this is based on Ben Eater's 8bit computer). But I'm using 9v battery instead of 5v one. I wonder why battery's voltage does not affect the de-bouncing circuit LED's light up time?
Math is pretty simple for calculating the time it lights up after button press but I wonder why voltage has nothing to do with calculation:

1000000 ohms (1M) x 1E-06 farads = LED stays lit up for 1 second

Comment: Not going to scan through a video, looking for a schematic somewhere. Post the diagram, preferably from the design software rather than a screenshot of a video.

Comment: Added schematic photo, it's taken straight out of Ben's video, I have identical setup.

Comment: Hint: what is the voltage across the cap compared to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage divider (consisting of the three resistors in series) works as a voltage reference for the comparators inside the NE555. This means, that a higher supply voltage also leads to a higher reference voltage (around 6V instead of 3.3V and 3V instead of 1.67V).
At the same time, the capacitor is charged faster, because more current flows through the 1M resistor.
If you did the math, you could see that these two effects cancel out.

To sum it up: The capacitor is charged faster, but at the same time it needs to be charged to a higher voltage to toggle the RS latch.

If you are interested in some further explanations, have a look at some tutorials explaining capacitor charge curves in detail (like [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html) one).

Answer (score 0):

The voltage is canceled out, because you compare the voltage of a voltage devider (R=1MOhm, C) with the voltage of a second voltage devider (the three resistors over each other).
If you change the voltage, then both levels change simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Q out is set by Threshold  (SW) going low and on Powerup then the Monostable times out and is reset by 1.1RC duration regardless of Vcc as Vthreshold rises above  2/3Vcc.

Threshold = \$Vin~+ = rises~ to ~~(1-\dfrac{1}{e})V_{CC}= 0.6321*Vcc  \$ when t=T=RC
Comparator Vin- reference \$Vin~- = \dfrac{10k}{15k}*Vcc  = 0.667 *Vcc\$

Thus the actual pulse width at logic level ampliude is \$t_{PW}= RC * \dfrac{0.667}{0.6321}=1.055RC \$

Now if they had changed the internal top R in the string from 5.0k to 5.38k to get the same exponential ratio for RC, **then it would have been PW=RC seconds**.
  Although the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Monostable) page says it should be T=ln(3)RC= 1.1*RC
from **2/3Vcc=Vcc(1-e^(-T/RC)** but close enuf for gov't work.